# DotNetCore 1.1 application compilation error: CS2007: Unrecognized option: '-' Web C:\..Microsoft.DotNet.Com

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I am getting a compilation error when I try to compile 1.1 application. I was converting this application from Rc1 to 1.1, made necessary changes to project files, packages restored without errors, but while compiling it is giving this error.

Also the solution had other web projects, referring the same common class libraries, all got compiled without any error...

In vs2015(on win10) , I installed these packages:

DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe

DotNetCore.1.0.1-SDK.1.0.0.Preview2-003131-x64.exe

```
------ Rebuild All started: Project: MyCommon.Model, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
  C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe build "c:\work\proj\Trunk\Gsb\MyCommon.Model" --configuration Debug --no-dependencies --no-incremental
  Project MyCommon.Model (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6) will be compiled because project is not safe for incremental compilation. Use --build-profile flag for more information.
  Compiling MyCommon.Model for .NETStandard,Version=v1.6
  Compilation succeeded.
      0 Warning(s)
      0 Error(s)
  Time elapsed 00:00:02.1608612
   (The compilation time can be improved. Run "dotnet build --build-profile" for more information)
------ Rebuild All started: Project: MyCommon.Utilities, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
  C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe build "c:\work\proj\Trunk\Gsb\MyCommon.Utilities" --configuration Debug --no-dependencies --no-incremental
  Project MyCommon.Utilities (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6) will be compiled because project is not safe for incremental compilation. Use --build-profile flag for more information.
  Compiling MyCommon.Utilities for .NETStandard,Version=v1.6
  Compilation succeeded.
      0 Warning(s)
      0 Error(s)
  Time elapsed 00:00:02.0359443
   (The compilation time can be improved. Run "dotnet build --build-profile" for more information)
------ Rebuild All started: Project: Gsbr.Web, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
  C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe build "c:\work\proj\Trunk\Gsb\Gsbr.Web" --configuration Debug --no-dependencies --no-incremental
  Project Gsbr.Web (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1) will be compiled because project is not safe for incremental compilation. Use --build-profile flag for more information.
  Compiling Gsbr.Web for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1
  C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe compile-csc @c:\work\proj\Trunk\Gsb\Gsbr.Web\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\dotnet-compile.rsp returned Exit Code 1
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(262,5): error : c:\work\proj\Trunk\Gsb\Gsbr.Web\error CS2007: Unrecognized option: '-'
  Compilation failed.
      0 Warning(s)
      1 Error(s)
  Time elapsed 00:00:33.7698291
========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

project.json is like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.0"  ,  
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "1.1.0",    
    "MyCommon.Model": "1.0.0-*",
    "MyCommon.Utilities": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http": "1.1.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
    "Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core": "2017.1.118",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.1.0",
    "System.Net.Http": "4.3.0"
  },


  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "warningsAsErrors": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "embed": "Views/**",
    "compile": {
      "exclude": [ "wwwroot", "node_modules" ] 
    }
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "Config/*.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

`project.json` or `Startup.cs` does not show any errors.

what am I doing wrong? what could be causing the error?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you run `dotnet build` from the command line? And what is the output of `dotnet --version`?

Comment: Yes I got the same error when ran dotnet build

Comment: >dotnet
    
    Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host
    
      Version  : 1.1.0
      Build    : 928f77c4bc3f49d892459992fb6e1d5542cb5e86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending several hours clueless, finally I found the problem was caused by a .cshtml filename with a "-" in it !!! After renaming that file the compiler started working and I could finally compile the project. The hyphen in the filename was causing the compiler to fail. The filename was created by visual studio when copying another file (filename - copy.cshtml)
Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I have just come across the same problem when embedding .sql scripts inside a dotnet core executable - was caused by a file name having a combination of spaces and a "-" character - "data-01.sql" was fine, "data - 01.sql" was a problem! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!